# Objective-C iPhone - YouTubePlugIn.webplugin/YouTubePlugIn warning

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to play a YouTube video within an iPhone app using the technique in this URL
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application

The technique works fine and the video plays fine, except that I'm getting this warning.
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/YouTubePlugIn.webplugin/YouTubePlugIn" (file not found).

That does slow down the app for the first time I got the warning. Seems like a lot of people is getting the same warning, but none of the forums I read seems to have the solution to get rid of the warning.

Do I need to download something or do specific things?
I also tried adding the YouTube framework from "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/YouTube.framework"
Doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Please enlight.

Comment: I have the same problem. On the device (iPod Touch).

Comment: Ok. I went to the youtube page containing the clip in particular and it said the clip wasn't available from mobiles. Might be worth checking if the clip is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your app on the device. The Simulator doesn't have the YouTube app.

Answer (score 0):

Some clips might not play in mobile devices. Check if you clips does.

The "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/dyld' has changed; re-reading symbols" warnings can be ignored (the clips should play anyway if it is available on mobile devices).

Note. I don't know the correct reason why some clips don't play on mobile, it might be a transcoding issue (not being transcoded for mobile) or some publisher settings. 
Would be interesting to know.